# Bash script check folder for file then move file to root directory and delete empty directory

Tags: bash, shell, sh, move

This should be simple.  I need to check each folder in a root directory for files and move the files from their directory to the root directory and remove that empty directory.  I've used this batch script in Windows but I would like to convert it to a bash script and I'm not too familiar with bash.

```
cd /d M:\
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /AD') do (
   cd "%%a"
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /AD') do (
      move "%%b" ..
   )
   move *.* ..
   cd ..
   rd "%%a"
)
```

Example:

`/root`

`/root/Test/1.txt`

`/root/1.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest solution (which might be overdoing things), is to just find all files in subdirectories for `root/` and move them to `root/`, and afterwards try to delete just all subdirectories of `root/`

```sh
find root/ -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 3 -type f -exec mv {} root/ ";"
rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty root/*/
```

this doesn't check whether there are multiple files of the same name (and it will just overwrite them). it will also remove any empty directories in `root/`.

another attempt that will only remove sub-directories if it contained a file that was moved:

```sh
root=root/

for f in "${root}"/*/*; do
  if [ -f "${f}" ]; then
    rm -f "${root}/${f##*/}"
    mv "${f}" "${root}"
    rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty "${f%/*}"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Sorry you were still editing it.  The first one works unless I have multiple folders. and the second I get the file is the same error.

Comment: sorry, if you get an error, you should say what it is. it's pretty hard to fix errors you don't know.

Comment: mv: '/root/test/test.txt' and '/root/test.txt' are the same file

Comment: well, you got a symlink in /root/ that points to the file you want to copy. you basically got a name collision, and it's not clear what you really want to do in that case.

Comment: Ok so for the error as and example I'd like to move the file test.txt from /root/test/test.txt to the root directory so I'd be left with /root/test.txt.  I don't want to change the name of the file just move it.

Comment: but what do you do with the existing `test.txt` symlink? ignore it? (if so, see my updated answer). what if the symlink points to something else?

Comment: Perfect.  Yes I didn't realize the file needed to be ignored.  Thank you for the help.